# How is 値 (あたい・ち・ね) read and when?

Tags: kanji, readings

Out of the three lectures ね is the easiest to predict for me because it is always related to a price as in 値が張る (which is the only place where I would read it ね when alone), this lecture can also be found in 値段 (the more casual word for 価格 (it may be worth noting that the 訓読み of 価 is あたい)), 高値 or 安値.

Things are a little unclear when 値 as the meaning of *value*. Technically, it should be read as あたい since it is its 訓読み, nevertheless I have heard Xに値｛ち｝を取る in a probability course and in some other settings I have heard 値 read as ち when isolated.

So I am wondering, how to read 値 when alone, how can I choose between ち and あたい?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12540/7810

Comment: btw I never heard of 値{ち}を取る, is it used in math or economics settings or something?

Comment: @broccoliforest Yes, I have heard it while attending a math course, it may have been a mistake but it confuses me. Xに値を取る means *taking values in X* (used in probability)

Comment: Hmm... I've only heard あたいをとる for that situation throughout my what little math education experience.

Comment: 「値をとる」は「あたいをとる」って読む気がします・・・　例えば[ここ](http://www.sansuu.net/kskakomon/ksq/ks081q.htm): 「どのような値（あたい）をとることができますか」

Comment: That would mean that there is no subtlety and every thing becomes clear again. Thank you. If one (or both) of you could both their comments as answers (just stating that ちをとる is a mistake) so that I can give you the rep you deserve and accept an answer.

Comment: I know "二値(にち)を取る". It takes binary value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The on-yomi of this kanji, ち, is not used alone; it only appears in compounds such as 中央値【ちゅうおうち】 (median), 平均値【へいきんち】 (mean), 最頻値【さいひんち】 (mode), 真偽値【しんぎち】 (boolean value).

If you just want to say *value* (of something) in mathematical/statistical/programming contexts, this kanji is always read as あたい.